# Schema evolution for avro, orc, parquet formats

Tags: schema, avro, parquet, orc

[image]

In terms of schema evolution, my understanding is that it should be a binary answer (yes or no). In the above picture though, it shows pie with 100%, 25% and 50% respectively. What is this concept?

Comment: Where did you find that image? Did it not describe itself?

Answer (score 1):

- **Avro** supports adding new columns, rename(Alias) and delete columns.
- **ORC** with Hive supports adding new columns and changing column types.
- **Parquet** supports addition of new columns.

Looks like this is what is represented using the images.